# How I can get questions where the body is the same as the title?

Tags: support, data-explorer, low-quality-posts, title, sql

It is know that many questions have the same body and title, So I wanted to [create a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210971/questions-where-the-body-is-equal-to-the-title) to show them all, but this don't work :

```sql
select
   Posts.id as [Post Link], -- Question title.
   Count(PendingFlags.PostId) as [Number of pending flags], -- Number of pending flags per questions.
   Posts.OwnerUserId as [User Link],
   Reputation as [User Reputation], -- Interesting to see that such questions are sometimes asked by high rep users.
   Posts.Score as [Votes],
   Posts.ViewCount,
   Posts.AnswerCount as [Number of Answers],
   Posts.FavoriteCount as [Number of Stars], -- Some questions seems to be very helpfull :) .
   Posts.CreationDate as [Asked on], -- The older is the question, the more is the chance that flags on them can't get reviewed.
   Posts.LastActivityDate as [last activity], -- Similar effect as with Posts.CreationDate.
   Posts.LastEditDate as [modified on]
from posts 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Users on Users.id = posts.OwnerUserId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN PendingFlags on PendingFlags.PostId = Posts.Id
where ClosedDate IS NULL -- The question is not closed.
   AND LOWER(body) = LOWER(Posts.title) -- This condition doesn't work : the query doesn't return any results...
group by Posts.id, Posts.OwnerUserId, body, Reputation, Posts.Score, Posts.FavoriteCount, Posts.AnswerCount, Posts.CreationDate, Posts.LastActivityDate, Posts.LastEditDate, Posts.ViewCount
order by Count(PendingFlags.PostId) desc; -- Questions with more flags have more chance to get them handled, and the higher is the probabilty that the question is off-topic (since several users already reviewed the question).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments to [animusons's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237257/242678), the rendered version of the body without tags can be found in the `PostHistory` table. You have to select the most recent entry with a `postHistoryTypeId` that is either `2` (initial body), `5` (edited body), or `8` (body rollback).

Here is a query that fetches the raw-text body using this approach to find all questions where the body is the same as the title (which returns a [table of more than 3000 posts on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219404/get-questions-where-title-is-same-as-body)):

```sql
SELECT p.Id AS [Post Link], p.Body
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 1
    AND LEN(Body) < LEN(Title) + 30
    AND LEN(Body) > LEN(Title)
) p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ph1.* FROM PostHistory ph1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PostId, MAX(CreationDate) AS CreationDate
    FROM PostHistory
    WHERE PostHistoryTypeId IN (2,5,8)
    GROUP BY PostId
  ) ph2
  ON ph1.PostId = ph2.PostId AND ph1.CreationDate = ph2.CreationDate
  WHERE PostHistoryTypeId IN (2,5,8)
) ph
ON p.Id = ph.PostId
WHERE LOWER(p.Title) = LOWER(ph.Text)
ORDER BY Title
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the Body contains the **rendered** version of the text. So even if they copy-paste the Title into the Body, it is *at minimum* going to be surrounded in a paragraph and end up looking like `<p>Body</p>`. If there are some other formatting things in the Title that don't get rendered in the Title but *do* get rendered in the Body, those will also produce some differences.

Comment: Ok thanks. So How I can get the raw text?

Comment: The raw-text version of a post is not available in the Data Explorer.

Comment: So does it mean my query is impossible to realize?

Comment: Well, you could wrap the Title in paragraph tags when doing the comparison to get *some* results. But as far as rendering the Title as HTML to get all possible matches, not aware of any way to do that.

Comment: Mabe with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/457701/2284570)?

Comment: Stripping the HTML would still only give you results where there is nothing that could be rendered in the Title. If the Title has `**something like this**`, the asterisks are going to get changed to `<b>` and `</b>` respectively in the Body, which would get stripped as HTML and still cause it to not match the Title.

Comment: You told it yourself, there is no rendering at all in the title.

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, so the asterisks will still be there in the Title. The problem is if the Title is simply copy-pasted, the asterisks will be *changed* into HTML in the Body. That causes the Title to be different from the Body. If you just strip the HTML from the Body, it will *still* be different from the Title.

Comment: It is available, you just have to get the appropriate `PostHistory` entry.

Comment: @TimStone Are all the revisions in the PostHistory table raw-text?

Comment: Yeah, they're all the source Markdown (or just text in the case of titles)

Comment: @TimStone : So which is the entry of `PostHistory`table I should chose?

Comment: @user2284570 So you could just look for PostHistoryTypeId 2, which is the Initial Body. Then you'd also want to make sure it has no TypeId 5 (Edit Body) which would suggest it's already been edited away from being an exact copy of the Title.

Comment: @user2284570 The latest one where `PostHistoryTypeId IN(2, 5, 8)`

Comment: @TimStone : May you detail this part in an answer please? *(at least the `where`close part)*