# Is it a bad practice to just include the question in the title?

Tags: discussion, title

Occasionally, I come across questions (specifically in Stack Overflow) where the actual question is just included as the title of the post but not in the text. 
So the text just explains the problem without ever including the question.

Is this a bad practice to include the question just in the title but not in the text? Personally I find it inconvenient, even though I read the title before clicking once I'm on the question I tend to focus on the text.

I will try to include examples of this as I come by them.

Comment: and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66119/title-only-questions-i-e-questions-without-body-should-be-allowed

Comment: and related to support your research: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237256/how-i-can-get-questions-where-the-body-is-the-same-as-the-title

Comment: and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/what-should-i-write-in-the-question-body-if-the-title-already-explains-everythin and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257760/what-do-you-do-if-you-have-only-a-question-title and I'm done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158703/asking-questions-in-the-title

Comment: If the body of a question, doesn't contain a question, I almost always vote to close the question for not being clear.  Good questions, actually ask a question within the body of the question (and use proper grammatical indicators to do that), I cannot think of an exception to that statement

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

<sub>I see no reason why this should be even debated about</sub>

Comment: Why? I see no reason why it shouldn't be debated

Comment: @Cai imagine reading a book with the title being the plot and the rest of the book just filler. Lame.

Comment: You can't compare Q&A to a novel. I see, in theory, nothing wrong with the 'title' being the main question and the 'body' being supportive information...